# Proving that a function on a $\sigma$-finite measure space is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(Y,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $U \subseteq
> \mathbb{R}$ open and $g \in \mathcal{L}^1(Y)$. Let $f: U \times Y \to
> \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f^y(x) := f(x,y)$ is continuous $\mu$-a.e.
>   and that $\int_Yf(x,y)d\mu(y)$ exists for any $x \in U$. Now define
>   $h:U \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$h(x) := \int_Yf(x,y)d\mu(y)$$ and show that
>   $h$ is continuous.

My idea was to use the definition of continuity. Since $f^y$ is continuous $\mu$-a.e. we have for any $x_0 \in U$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$|x - x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f^y(x) - f^y(x_0)| < \varepsilon$$ holds $\mu$-a.e.
Let $Y = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Y_n$ with $Y_n$ increasing and $\mu(Y_n) < \infty$. Then we have for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $|x - x_0| < \delta/\mu(Y_n)$ $$|h(x)\chi_{Y_n} - h(x_0)\chi_{Y_n}| \leq \int_Y|f(x,y) - f(x_0,y)|\chi_{Y_n}d \mu(y) < \varepsilon $$ By $\lim_{n \to \infty}h\chi_{Y_n} = h$ we get that $$|h(x) - h(x_0)| < \varepsilon$$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \lim_{n \to \infty} \varepsilon/\mu(Y_n)$. Now my problem is, that $\delta = 0$ might occur which is really bad. Is there any way to fix the proof?

**Remark.** I want to use $\delta-\epsilon$-definition of continuity.

Comment: You mention $g$ once, but never use it. I expect that its use will be crucial (in an application of the dominated convergence theorem).

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. Totally forgot. It should be that $|f(x,y)| \leq g(y)$ for $\mu$-a.e $y$ and all $x \in U$. Crucial indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to work with sequences. Let $x$ be a fixed point in $U$, and $x_n$ be a sequence that converges to $x$. Let us prove that $h(x_n)$ converges to $h(x)$.

Let $f_n: y\mapsto f(x_n,y)$ and $f':y\mapsto f(x,y)$. The hypothesis "$|f(x,y)| \leq g(y)$ for $\mu$-a.e $y$ and all $x\in U$" translates to $|f_n(y)|\leq g(y)$ for $\mu$-a.e $y$.

Moreover, note that since $f^y(x) := f(x,y)$ is continuous $\mu$-a.e, $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f'$ $\mu$-a.e.

Lebesgue dominated convergence applies and yields: $$\lim_n\int f_n d\mu = \int f' d\mu$$ which rewrites as $\lim_n h(x_n) = h(x)$. Hence continuity.